# Using this in method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have a problem catching my object data in jQuery methods:

```
this.start = function() {
            var prepend = '<img id = "' + this.imageList[0].name + '" class = "desktop_image_slider_prepended_image" src = "res/img/' + this.imageList[0].name + '.png"></img>';
            $("#desktop_image_slider").prepend(prepend);
            this.boxList.shift(this.imageList[0]);
            $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).animate({"width":"0%"}, 500);
            $("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, function() {
                $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).remove();
                this.imageList.push(this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1]);
                this.boxList.splice(this.boxList.length-1, 1);
                $timeout(function() {
                    this.start();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
```

It throws undefined. It is obviously taking something from jQuery not from my method. Is there a way to access my method?

Thanks!

Comment: The `this` referenced in your animate function event handler is referencing the calling event function.  Not your global `this`.  You can either use `.bind(this)` or use `const _self = this;` and then reference `_self.imageList`.

Comment: use @VtoCorleone reply as it is the proper way to use this in Jquery

Comment: Yes that the best way and I was able to make it work with Your comment, You were the first to answer You should post an answer so I can vote it if You would like.

Comment: Just posted an answer for the street cred.  Glad this worked @EnvironmentGenerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` referenced in your animate function event handler is referencing the calling event function. Not your global `this`. You can either use `.bind(this)` or use `const _self = this;` and then reference `_self.imageList`

This example uses `const _self = this`.

```
start = function() {
    var prepend = '<img id = "' + this.imageList[0].name + '" class = "desktop_image_slider_prepended_image" src = "res/img/' + this.imageList[0].name + '.png"></img>';
    $("#desktop_image_slider").prepend(prepend);
    this.boxList.shift(this.imageList[0]);
    $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).animate({"width":"0%"}, 500);
    var _self = this;
    $("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, function() {
        $("#" + _self[_self.boxList.length-1].name).remove(); // _self is used instead of this
        _self.imageList.push(_self.boxList[_self.boxList.length-1]); // _self is used instead of this
        _self.boxList.splice(_self.boxList.length-1, 1); // _self is used instead of this
        $timeout(function() {
            _self.start(); // _self is used instead of this
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

This example uses `bind`

```
this.start = function() {
    var prepend = '<img id = "' + this.imageList[0].name + '" class = "desktop_image_slider_prepended_image" src = "res/img/' + this.imageList[0].name + '.png"></img>';
    $("#desktop_image_slider").prepend(prepend);
    this.boxList.shift(this.imageList[0]);
    $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).animate({"width":"0%"}, 500);
    $("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, function() {
        $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).remove();
        this.imageList.push(this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1]);
        this.boxList.splice(this.boxList.length-1, 1);
        $timeout(function() {
            this.start();
        }.bind(this), 1000); // set function's scope to `this`
    }.bind(this)); // set function's scope to `this`
```

Answer (score 2):

try to pass the **object this** as a parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you go into another function context, *this* will be different. Therefore, store this in another variable first

```
start = function() {
            var prepend = '<img id = "' + this.imageList[0].name + '" class = "desktop_image_slider_prepended_image" src = "res/img/' + this.imageList[0].name + '.png"></img>';
            $("#desktop_image_slider").prepend(prepend);
            this.boxList.shift(this.imageList[0]);
            $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).animate({"width":"0%"}, 500);
            var oldThis = this;
            $("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, function() {
                $("#" + oldThis.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).remove();
                oldThis.imageList.push(this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1]);
                oldThis.boxList.splice(this.boxList.length-1, 1);
                $timeout(function() {
                    oldThis.start();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you define an anonymous function to be called at a later time you will lose your expected `this`.  One way to fix it is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), for example:

```
this.start = function() {
    var prepend = '<img id = "' + this.imageList[0].name + '" class = "desktop_image_slider_prepended_image" src = "res/img/' + this.imageList[0].name + '.png"></img>';
    $("#desktop_image_slider").prepend(prepend);
    this.boxList.shift(this.imageList[0]);
    $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).animate({"width":"0%"}, 500);
    $("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, function() {
        $("#" + this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1].name).remove();
        this.imageList.push(this.boxList[this.boxList.length-1]);
        this.boxList.splice(this.boxList.length-1, 1);
        $timeout(function() {
            this.start();
        }.bind(this), 1000); // bind this to timeout callback
    }.bind(this)); // bind this to animate callback
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the arrow function to maintain the same `this` for the anonymous function lexical context:

```
$("#" + this.imageList[0].name).animate({"width":"11.1111111111%"}, 500, () => {
  ... with this
}
```